# How can I rewrite index.php to xxx.php?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want the following two routes to be set in this way:

- Route 1: `/post/123` -> `app.php`
- Route 2: `/?p=123` -> `app.php?p=123`

Currently what I have in .htaccess is

```
RewriteRule ^$ app\.php [L]
RewriteRule post/(.*)$ app\.php [L]
```

How can I achieve route 2?

Comment: Your rule already does that. The query string is appended to the end automatically

Comment: @JonLin somehow I got 500 internal server error for my first rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in one rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(post/.+)?$ app.php [L,NC]
```